# Storing instances of class having inner-classes into a mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP class which will have at least two inner-classes. I want to store the instances of this class into a mySQL database so that I can get all the data in a bulk instead of going through multiple number of tables.

So far, I have looked up serializing in PHP and storing them into a BLOB field of the database. However, with a object-class having inner-object-classes I am not sure how it will turn out or even is it possible at all? I could not find any helpful resources on this topic specifically.

Comment: Why do you want to store PHP classes in a database?

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/table-per-class-inheritance.html  (several strategies for class inheritance, these general principles apply to other languages and ORM)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368545/oop-php-how-to-avoid-each-class-for-each-table-situation

Comment: I am creating a web application that holds a huge amount of information of a user with many sub-sections.  I am just thinking possibly a better way of managing those data while storing in a table.

Answer (score 0):

**What you are looking for is ORM**, since serializing an object and storing in a database is **almost never the solution**. [This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368545/oop-php-how-to-avoid-each-class-for-each-table-situation) is a nice thread for ORM benefits and their intricacies.

[ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) allows you to map specific parts of an objects to difference fields, using multiple tables, all the way down to its most basic structures. It can handle one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, and perform operations on creation that **give you more creative freedom and elegance in your code**.

It is *much* faster than storing a serialized object because there are smaller more optimized queries performed.

**The main advantages of ORM are:**

1. Ability to use class inheritance
2. Built in validation for data structure security and efficiency
3. Prebuilt queries and methods on objects.

**Disadvantages of ORM:**

1. Boilerplate to set up.
2. More abstract than serializing an object.